# How to run Chariot using python script? "This app can't run on your PC"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cmd

Everyone. I met a issue says that "This app can't run on your PC" when I want to run the a .exe file using python script. The thing is I could run it in Command Prompt, it works well. but when I want to run it using python script in VS Code, it says [image]

I tried many methods google from the Internet, it still doesn't work. Here is what I want to run in python

```
    os.system(" cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia\IxChariot ")
    os.system(" runtst.exe -t20 C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\IxChariot\\Tests\\mlo_delay.tst C:\\csv\\6G_d.tst ")
```

Does anyone have idea what is the issue and how to fix it? thx

Comment: every `os.system()` uses own shell/environment and if you change directory in one `os.system()` then other `os.system()` wiil use older directory. You would have to run both command in one `os.system()` using `;`  - `"cd ... ; runtst.exe ..."` - or you should use `os.chdir("C:\\...")`

Comment: in `cd ...` you also have to use `\\ ` in path  - `"cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Ixia\\IxChariot"` And I'm not sure but it may need to use \ before space to inform system that it is part of path, not separation between parameters `"cd C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Ixia\\IxChariot"`

Answer (score -1):

First, please set **permissions** for your vscode. It seems that it runs files in the system disk. Then, you can use `os.popen()` to open files.
For example:

```
import os

google = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

os.popen(google)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, it does not define the working/start in directory when running the, completely different, executable; and it does not pass it multiple arguments/parameters.